# MS-Excel - Split cell into rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data in excel in the form of

```
cell1 | cell2
1     | A, B, C
2     | A, D
```

And I want to split the comma separated data into new rows.

Like,

```
   cell1 | cell2
   1     | A
   1     | B
   1     | C
   2     | A
   2     | D
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying From Jook's answer.

```
Public Sub solutionJook()
  Dim arr() As Variant
  Dim arrSum() As Variant
  Dim arrResult() As Variant
  Dim arrTemp As Variant

  Dim i As Long
  Dim j As Long
  Dim h As Long
  Dim lngSplitColumn As Long
  'input of array to seperate
  arr = Range("A2:C3")
  'specify which column has the values to be split up
  lngSplitColumn = 2

  'using the boundries of the given range,
  'arrSum has now always the right boundries for the first dimension
  ReDim Preserve arrSum(LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2), 1 To 1)

  'create the array with seperated A B C
  For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    'use split to make A B C into an array, using 'enter' (chr(10)) as indicator
    arrTemp = Split(arr(i, lngSplitColumn), " | ")
    'every value of arrTemp creates a new row
    For j = LBound(arrTemp) To UBound(arrTemp)
      'loop through all input columns and create the new row
      For h = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If h = lngSplitColumn Then
          'setup the value of the splitted column
          arrSum(h, UBound(arrSum, 2)) = arrTemp(j)  'set A,B,C
        Else
          'setup the value of any other column
          arrSum(h, UBound(arrSum, 2)) = arr(i, h) 'set Value of Column h
        End If
      Next h

      ReDim Preserve arrSum(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 2), _
                            LBound(arrSum, 2) To (UBound(arrSum, 2) + 1))
    Next j
  Next i

  'clean up last empty row (not realy necessary)
  ReDim Preserve arrSum(LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 2), _
                        LBound(arrSum, 2) To (UBound(arrSum, 2) - 1))

  'setup transposed result array
  ReDim arrResult(LBound(arrSum, 2) To UBound(arrSum, 2), _
                  LBound(arrSum, 1) To UBound(arrSum, 1))

  'transpose the array
  For i = LBound(arrResult, 1) To UBound(arrResult, 1)
    For j = LBound(arrResult, 2) To UBound(arrResult, 2)
      arrResult(i, j) = arrSum(j, i)
    Next j
  Next i

  'specify target range
  Range(Cells(1, 5), Cells(UBound(arrResult, 1), 4 + UBound(arrResult, 2))) = arrResult

End Sub
```